# cookies are not accessible from getServerSideProps in NextJs

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, next.js

i have an issue when trying to send the cookies from browser to nextJs server
first let me describe the issue :

- my backend API is built with Nodejs and express, the frontend is
  handled by Nextjs , when the user try to login the token is stored as
  an httpOnly cookie ,to get the loggedin user i must send the cookie
  from my frontend to my backend so i do that through nextJs
  getServerSideProps function with the help of
  **Context.req.headers.cookie** in order to sent this token to my nodeJs
  backend.
  this is the login controller (backend):

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req,res,next)=>{
    // SOME CODE
    const token = jwt.sign({id: user.id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const cookieOption = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN*24*60*60*1000),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure : true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        // domain: '.herokuapp.com'
    };

    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOption);
    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: {
            user
        }
    })

});
```

and this is my getServerSideProps function in which i try to send the token from nextJs to nodeJs server:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context){

 console.log(context.req.headers.cookie) // EMPTY OBJECT!
 console.log(context.req.cookies) //EMPTY OBJECT TOO

 let user
try{
    const res = await fetch(`${url}/users/isLoggedin`, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials:'include',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            Cookie: req.headers.cookie
        },
    })
    const data = await res.json()
    if(!res.ok){
        throw data 
    }
    user = data   
}catch(err){
    return console.log(err)
}

return {
 props: {
   user,
 }
 }
}
```

i can send the token from browser directly to nodeJs (client side) but i can't send the token from the browser to nextJs server i don't know why, i have tried many solutions but no ones workes for me .

- **note**: both backend and frontend are deployed to heroku

Comment: _"both backend and frontend are deployed to heroku"_ - Are they deployed under the same domain/subdomain?

Comment: @juliomalves yes ,frontend: frontend.herokuapp.com ,  backend: backend.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same. I was able to read the token from the client side but not from `getServerSideProps`.

What solved it was to explicitly set the cookie domain in `res.cookie` in the backend. Let's say frontend domain was `frontend.webapp` and backend domain was `backend.webapp`. The code would be as follows:

```js
res.cookie('authtoken',token, { httpOnly: true, domain: '.webapp.com' })
```